# Как в google sheets сложить числа в одном табе (sheet) и сумму этих числел вывести в отдельный tab?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Есть задача:
В одном табе, d1, в колонке А есть ячейки со значением test, напротив них, в колонке Б, есть числовые значения 5 и 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно сложив эти значения, перенести их в таб общее ячейку b2?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какую для этого нужно прописать формулу?
Спасибо.

Comment: Откуда взялась дата?

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA руками была вписана

Answer (score 0):

На листе "Общее" в ячейке B2 пишите следующую формулу

```
=СУММ('Общее'!B2:B)
```

И всё готово